# Excel: Identify 2+ Separate Instances of Values in a Row for a Given Range

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, row

[image]

The image above is a spreadsheet of staff members down the left and the days of the year across the top. Weekends are in blue.

What I would like to achieve for each row for a given range of dates is to identify two or more separate occurrences of absence. Some of the codes qualify as an absence i.e. IL - Illness, PR - Personal Reasons, some don't i.e. DE - Dentist, MW - Midwife.

The top row is a good example of a row that has two or more separate absences.

One absence is not limited to one day, so if there were concurrent absences a bit like the MA examples then they would count as one absence. Although MA wouldn't count as it stands for maternity.

Apologies for not providing any code as I'm stuck where to start. Even a hint in the right direction would be helpful.

Comment: I suggest writing it out as a protocol  - something like 'for each leave of absence which is in the first list there is another leave of absence separated from it by one or more days which are not weekends'. There may be people out there who can offer a formula solution, but IMO VBA would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to have weekends in your data?

I have a solution using SUMPRODUCT but it doesn't handle absences over weekends as a single block (e.g. the MA block).
[Here is a screenshot of some dummy data based on your request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YKkc8.png).

The formulae in column AI are based on this in AI3:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B3:AG3<>"-")*(B3:AG3<>"")*(A3:AF3="-")*1)+SUMPRODUCT((B3:AG3<>"-")*(B3:AG3<>"")*(A3:AF3="")*1)
```

The first term in the first sumproduct formula determines which columns in the range (B to AG) have no absences (indicated by the dash).

The second term determines which columns are weekends (blanks).

The third term determines which previous columns (half-days) have no absences (dash) - it will be necessary to have a blank column before the data (ie. column A as shown in this example - this can be hidden).

The second sumproduct formula does the same thing but the third term handles where the previous half-day was a weekend (blank).

As you can see this works for all except the single block of MA absence. If you were to remove the weekend columns the formula could be simplified.

Comment: I think this is worth a vote for good basic idea. I can imagine how you could deal with weekends either using networkdays() or testing date for a weekday, but would add a lot of complexity.